# PHP: MATCH AGAINST does not work for certain stopwords but works for others (with no obvious logic to it)

Tags: php, mysql, match, stop-words

I am using WAMP on my computer for a searchable database which utilizes a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH (field_01, field_02, field_03, field_04, field_05, field_06, field_07, field_08, field_09) AGAINST('\"$searchterm\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY field_01,field_10,field_11,field_12 ASC
```

I have a full index with fields 01 to 09, and this setup has worked nicely on my previous computer (WAMP installation at least 5 years old).

However, on my new computer (WAMP installation with MySQL version 5.7.31) it only works selectively, i.e. it sometimes returns no result.

I have researched the issue and stopwords seemed like the key to the solution because the zero-result issue occurs for search words like 'why', 'for', 'and', 'or'.

I have tried the ft_stopword_file="" method (restarting WAMP and repairing the table). Didn't help.

And the strange thing is that the very same query works for the search word 'what' and several other stopwords listed in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

At this point I am unable to see any logic to the behavior of this query and I hope someone can point out what I may have missed. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why exactly do you want to do this in MySQL?

Comment: It is a rather convoluted system that was created several years ago. Now I simply want to relocate it to a new computer and make it work there. I have managed to solve most of the issues that cropped up in the process but this one got me stumped.

Comment: Well there are a few good reasons to refactor this. For one if your primary issue was legacy then here's your chance to refactor. The list of stop words need not be viewed as a horizontal domain. Instead of fields think rows. It becomes easier to SELECT all words or match against as in `IN` clause. If you're using a flat file it's the same problem in PHP, think `in_array()` or the like.

Comment: Thank you, Sherif.

Comment: What ENGINE is being used?  Presumably InnoDB?  But `ft_stopword` implies MyISAM?

Comment: Please show us an actual `SELECT` and `CREATE TABLE`.  (There may be datatype issues, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, Rick James, I failed to notice your questions before. The issue is solved now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the word "what" works for you, which is a stopword for both InnoDB and MyISAM, this issue doesn't seem to be related to stopwords (or at least not after you disabled the stopword list).

The most likely reason is that *short* words are not indexed. Check your setting for [`ft_min_word_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len), which defaults to a minimum word lenght of 4 (for MyISAM) and would thus exclude e.g. `for` but not `what`, matching your situation. After changing it, you have to recreate your fulltext index (again). You may have adjusted that setting on your old server and forgot about it, so check it there too if that server is still available.

Or maybe you used InnoDB there, where the corresponding setting [`innodb_ft_min_token_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) defaults to 3, so most of your test words would have worked out-of-the-box. Also check that value on your new server in case you are currently using InnoDB. Although I assume you would have remembered explicitly increasing that value to 4, it might be a default setting in your wamp setup for some reason.